# How do I avoid two filters when condition involves an Optional

Tags: java, option-type

I have code like this:

```
myList.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getName().isPresent())
            .filter(item -> item.getName().get().equalsIgnoreCase(otherName))
            .findFirst();
```

(... where `item.getName()` has a return type of `Optional<String>`)

How can I condense two filters into one here?

Comment: Is `otherName` a `String` that's known to not be `null`? Then just `item -> otherName.equals(item.getName().orElse(null))` should work. Because `someString.equals(null)` will just return `false` as long as `someString` isn't `null`.

Comment: Another variant would be `item.getName().map(otherName::EqualsIgnoreCase).orElse(false)` if you know that otherName is nonnull. Otherwise `item.getName().map(n -> n.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)`).orElse(false)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Optional.filter()`:

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(item -> 
        item.getName().filter(n -> n.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)).isPresent())
    .findFirst();
```

The inner `filter` call is `Optional.filter`, which returns an empty optional if the filter condition was not met.

Comment: or `filter(otherName::equalsIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Yes. I just thought maybe the OP is using value from`item.getName()` because `otherName` may be null. But I might be imagining that, @Holger

Comment: Well, when `otherName` is `null`, it would be pointless to search for a name that is present and matches `null` at the same time. So I’d say, the developer should decide. Either, `otherName` in allowed to be `null`, the check and handle it upfront, or it is not, then throwing an NPE is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid it with [`Optional::stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream()) method:

> If a value is present, returns a sequential Stream containing only that value, otherwise returns an empty Stream.

```
myList.stream()
  .map(Item::getName)
  .flatMap(Optional::stream)
  .filter(otherName::equalsIgnoreCase)
  .findFirst();
```

Comment: Nice option. Worth pointing out that it's java 9+. And perhaps `otherName::equalsIgnoreCase` may need a null check.

Comment: The problem is that this will find a name instead of an `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it the "OOP" way. Make a method in Item 'isNameEqual' or something like that which would hide the logic with the optional and the ignore case.

Then you can have just 1 filter statement with Item::isNameEqual.

You don't want to have too much ceremony in the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the filters using a logical AND (`&&`):

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.getName().isPresent() 
        && item.getName().get().equalsIgnoreCase(otherName))
    .findFirst();
```

This is safe because if the value is not present, the `&&` will short-circuit to false.

Or use the conditional operator:

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.getName().isPresent()  
        ? item.getName().get().equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)
        : false)
    .findFirst();
```

Another way would be to use `null` as the value if the `Optional<String>` has no value and `equalsIgnoreCase(null)` will always return `false`:

```
myList.stream()
    .filter(item -> otherName.equalsIgnoreCase(item
        .getName()
        .orElseGet(null)))
    .findFirst();
```